# Mysqli not inserting data on table

Tags: mysqli

Here's my code:

```
            // Register User
            $sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, password, email, register_date)
            VALUES ('$username', '$md5pass', '$email', '$date')";
            if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
                $last_id = mysqli_insert_id($conn);
                $sql = "INSERT INTO skills (user_id)
                VALUES ('$last_id')" or die(mysqli_error($conn));
            } else {
                echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
            }
```

Well the first table is created and everything seems ok but the second table (skills) it's not being inserted.
Can anyone tell what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you please change your title to something more descriptive of the problem you're having?

Comment: as far as I can see, you are not actually executing the second insert statement? you create the SQL but never process it.

Comment: Well I want to Insert data in the table users and then pickup the user_id and insert it in the table skills. 
All the tables are already created and the first table is filled with the data. I made the same thing for the second table and nothing..

Answer (score 0):

You create the second insert query, but you are not executing it.

Also, you should be checking the result of `mysqli_insert_id`, in case this call fails.